# Weird Error Pandas Groupby : works with .sum(), but throws error with .rank()

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, categorical-data

Rephrasing my error.

I am working with a multiindex dataframe.

Applying:

```
df.groupby(level).sum()
```

**Works FINE**

However, applying:

```
df.groupby(level).rank()
```

throws me the following error:

```
ValueError: Categorical categories must be unique
```

Important note: I am working with 4 levels. I am grouping by using the first 3 levels. The fourth level is a vector of dates, the same for all the index levels.
The error is threw only when my overall multiindex dataframe exceeds 10000 rows. Using tail(), I noticed that when it is 9990 rows, it gives me the rank... adding an additional day throws me the error.

I checked the specific day, but it looks fine.

I then added additional layers in the first three levels, and the scenario repeats itself. Adding additional layers means that i need to select fewer lines by index level to get the result.

**Anyone had this error before? I am having a very hard time understanding where it comes from.**

Comment: df.groupby(level).apply(lambdax:x)

Comment: it's probably not the length, but the names of the actual keys - instead of using tail, try using iloc on some values in the middle like [-10500:-9500] etc... that may help nail down the rows that are causing the problem....

Comment: Basically I've four levels. One of the levels is a vector of dates. When doing my groupby, I select the first three levels, except the dates. When changing the lenght of my dataframe, the only thing that changes is the length of the date level. The other do not change. This is why I find it weird that after 10,000 rows, it gives me this error.

Comment: Also, sometimes I add additional layers on the first 3 levels, and the error arises again, at the 10000 rows ceil.